# VMware Windows 10 VM goes black

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, boot, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 VM where i wanted to reinstall VMware Tools. I removed it, restarted and then reinstalled it. After that the screen went black. I have tried things like:

- Restarting the VM
- Stopping and starting the VM
- Increased the video memory to 32 MB (And set it to automatic)
- Pressing F8 to go into safe mode

I cannot RDP into the VM

I can however somewhat use the vSphere console. I can use it for:

- Soft reboot the VM.
- Shows the VM POST'ing
- Go into the BIOS menu and edit settings

But when booting the VM normally it goes like this:

- POST
- Black/blank screen

Anyone who have tried the same or similar, who might be able to help?

Comment: Boot from Windows 10 installation media and run Startup Repair?

Comment: @MichaelHampton For some reason i had a brainfart, so i didnt try to use the DNS address when RDP'ing the VM.. Of course the VM had changed IP after reinstalling VMware Tools. The vSphere console still doesn't work, but its fine.

Comment: exactly which version of esxi are you running

Comment: @Chopper3 ESXI 6.0 Build 2494585

Answer (score 1):

For some reason i had a brainfart, so i didnt try to use the DNS address when RDP'ing the VM.. Of course the VM had changed IP after reinstalling VMware Tools.